# Can the Scatter spell send targets under water/lava/etc.?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

XGE pg 164, Scatter

> You teleport each affected target to an unoccupied space that you can see within 120 feet of you. That space must be on the ground or on a floor.

**Water**

You're on a boat and cast scatter on someone else on the boat.  If the water is less than 120 feet deep and you are looking over the side of the boat, could you teleport them to the bottom?

**Lava**

You're on an active volcano next to a pool of lava.  Can you scatter them into the lava?  You technically can't see the ground under it, so if you can send someone underwater could you not do it with lava?  Or does lava count as ground since you can technically walk on it (assuming we're using real lava not action movie lava)?

**Ice**

You're next to a frozen lake.  Can you scatter someone under the ice?

Comment: I've edited out the parts of my question that were answered in that other question but still have points that are unclear, did I edit it sufficiently for that to be apparent?

Comment: The other answer specifies that the "ground" seems to be whatever solid surface the characters are standing on. Does that no inform you rquestion?

Comment: Does "in lava" count as an occupied space, does it count as a liquid or a solid, etc.?  Is underwater a legal place to teleport someone, any rules preventing it?

Comment: Should I create a separate question "is lava ground"?  Is underwater an occupied space?  It's occupied by water?